# Spring Retry in a lambda function doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I've got a lambda function built with Spring Boot which makes a REST call to a service which can accept 10 requests per second. After those 10 requests I get back a 403.

Trying to get a method to work within this constraint has proven difficult.

At the moment my code looks as

```
@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class HttpUtil {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 60, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000, multiplier = 2))
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendPostRequest(@NonNull final MultiValueMap<String, Object> data, @NonNull final String url) {
        final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(data, new HttpHeaders());

        return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
    }
}
```

However if I fire off this and check the logs I can see the 403 exception being thrown over and over again, and no "backing off" period seems to be happening.

I attempted to extend `RetryListenerSupport` to add more logging so I can see the actual back off period, but that seems to have been ignored, despite being loaded. Does that need to be used with a RetryTemplate` rather than just the annotation?

Otherwise is there something obviously wrong with my annotation? or is there a much simpler way to achieve a "10 request per second cap" on my method?

edit:

Configuration class

```
@EnableRetry
@Configuration
public class RetryTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        final RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.registerListener(new DefaultListenerSupport());
        return retryTemplate;
    }
}
```

And a very simple listener

```
@Slf4j
public class DefaultListenerSupport extends RetryListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(final RetryContext context,
                                               final RetryCallback<T, E> callback, final Throwable throwable) {

        log.info("onClose {}", throwable.getMessage());

        super.close(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(final RetryContext context,
                                                 final RetryCallback<T, E> callback, final Throwable throwable) {

        log.info("onError {}", throwable.getMessage());

        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(final RetryContext context,
                                                 final RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {

        log.info("onOpen");

        return super.open(context, callback);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Do you have `@EnableRetry` on a configuration class?

Comment: Yes I do sorry, the same place the `@Bean` is configured to attach the listener.

Comment: and your `@UtilityClass` annotation is a meta-annotation that contains one of the spring annotations like `@Component` etc, I assume?

Comment: `> ignored ` = You can't just add ` RetryTemplate` `@Bean` and expect it to be used. To use a custom `RetryTemplate` you have to build an interceptor and use it in the annotation. You don't really need a listener, just enable DEBUG logging, to see the retry activity. If you see none, then @aarbor is probably right, you are not invoking it through the proxy with the retry interceptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class using the `@Retryable` annotation needs to be a Spring bean, otherwise you will need to use the `RetryTemplate` directly instead of the annotation.

If you don't want your class to be a bean, you can do:

```
private static final RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    static {
         SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
         retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(60);
         ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
         backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);
         backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(10000);
         retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
         retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    }
    private void doSomething() {
        retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
            return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This was correct, I'd simply missed the `@Component` when refactoring. Thanks for the spot.